# How to get the performance logs in leadfoot internjs?

Tags: intern, leadfoot

SImilar to protractor, I'm looking for some info on getting performance logs in leadfoot of internjs.

Below is only an example of getting logs in protractor

```
browser.manage().logs().get('performance').then(function (browserLog) {
    if (browserLog.length > 0)
         JSON.parse(JSON.stringiy(browserLog)).forEach(function (browserLog) {
         console.log('log: ' + browserLog.message);
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if performance logs are available, you can use Leadfoot's `getLogsFor()` function. Depends on the environment as far as what types of logs are available. You can use `getAvailableLogTypes()` to find that out for your use case.

According to the [documentation](https://theintern.io/leadfoot/module-leadfoot_Command.html#getLogsFor):

> ```
> getLogsFor(type: string): Promise.<Array.<LogEntry>>
> ```
>
> Gets all logs from the remote environment of the given type. The logs
> in the remote environment are cleared once they have been retrieved.

Comment: @a lead alcove Thank you. I could get the performance logs and all the traces successfully.